# Java socket is not recieving a response from the Print Writer

Tags: java

Server starts here:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Server has started");
    try {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(17000);
        while(true){
        ThreadedClass w;
        w = new ThreadedClass(socket.accept());
        Thread t = new Thread(w);
        t.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("Failed");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then this class:

```
package com.sandislandsrv.rourke750;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ThreadedClass implements Runnable{

private Socket socket;

public ThreadedClass(Socket socket){
    this.socket = socket;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    MysqlDataClass db = Start.getData();
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        String cred = in.readLine();
        String[] creds = cred.split(" ");
        System.out.print(creds[0] + creds[1]);
        boolean authenticate = db.getUsernamePassValid(creds[0], creds[1]);
        if (!authenticate){
            System.out.println("Failed to log in, bad password");
            out.println("BAD");
            out.close();
            return;
        }
        out.println("GOOD");
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            if (line.equals("END")){
                out.close();
                return;
            }
            if (line.equals("GET")){
                out.println(db.getMessages(creds[0]));
            }
            if (line.equals("IN")) break;
            if (line.equals("REMOVE")){
                line = in.readLine();
                db.removeMessage(creds[0], line);
            }
            }
        line = in.readLine();
        String[] format = line.split("Theamjgfdngkngfd8998906504906595665");
        String[] timeformat = format[1].split(":");
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        if (Long.parseLong(timeformat[0]) != 0)
            time += 3600 * Long.parseLong(timeformat[0]);
        if (Long.parseLong(timeformat[1]) != 0)
            time += 60 * Long.parseLong(timeformat[1]);
        if (Long.parseLong(timeformat[2]) != 0)
            time += Long.parseLong(timeformat[2]);
        db.addMessage(creds[0], format[0], time);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void remove(){

}
```

}

Then later on I call this method

```
public String[] getNames(){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("share.betterassociations.com", 17000);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out.println(username.getText().toString() + " " + password.getText().toString());
        System.out.print("test");
        String passed = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("test2");
        if (passed.equals("BAD")) {
            System.out.print("fail");
            loginerror.setVisible(true);
            socket.close();
            return null;
        }
        System.out.print("test2");
        out.println("GET");
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null){
            if (line.equals("END")) break;
            builder.append(line);
        }
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString().split(" ");
}
```

For some reason it seems to get frozen in the last method posted with the String passed = input.readLine();

I don't understand why its happening because I am sending a string to the client from the server but the client isn't receiving it.

Comment: You will be getting a `NullPointerException` in the server thread when the client closes the socket and `readLine()` returns null. You're detecting that case but then you're falling through into code that doesn't know about it, keeps reading, will get another null, doesn't check, etc etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a call to out.flush() after you write to it for both server and clients' outputStreams, like here

```
....
out.println("GOOD");
out.flush();
....
```

Alternatively, enable autoflushing by changing your server (the client is already enabled) here:

```
....
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
....
```

But per the documentation:
 if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output.

So don't get gotchya'ed

Comment: I thought out.println auto flushed?

Comment: @rourke750 Where in the Javadoc does it say that? You're constructing a `PrintWriter` from an `OutputStream.` which 'creates a new `PrintWriter,` *without* automatic line flushing, from an existing `OutputStream`' [my emphasis].

Comment: @EJP, It looks like he did enable autoflushing, but only on the client. This was probably the source of the confusion for him and me.